# windows 8 localization

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I've got few questions about localization apps in Windows 8.

1. Is there a way to automatic bind translations to UI element apart from element type? Currently I must provide string with id like "welcomeText.text" for textblock and "welcomeButton.Content" for button. It makes creating files with translations more complicated.
2. Does Windows 8 has similar solutions to this -> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals ?

Thank you in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think the answer to both questions is no.

As for question 1:

If you use the standard way of localizing Windows 8 apps you will have to specify the property, which is not great but understandable; how else would the platform know to what property it should bind? Perhaps I want to bind the Header property instead of the Content property.

There is no way for the platform to determine what I want unless I specify it.